# In Flutter how to access arguments from Modal route.of(context) (Named Route) outside the build context for example in function or init state

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am developing a weather app in flutter and I have a problem that I am using Named routes and I am accessing arguments with the help of Modal Route but while accessing arguments outside of buildcontext it is showing error 'Undefined name 'args'. Can anyone please help me out It will of great help Thank You as previously I was using constructors to pass the data between different screens But It is too messy so I switched to Named Routes.

My Welcome Screen

```
import 'package:weather_app/utilities/constants.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WelcomeScreen> createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: kPrimaryColor,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 120,
              ),
              Image.asset(
                'images/welcome_screen_pic.png',
                height: 250,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 120,
              ),
              // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
              Text(
                'Discover the Weather\nin Your City',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: kWelcomeScreenTitle,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
              Text(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                'Get to know your weather maps and\nradar precipitation forecast',
                style: kWelcomeScreenTagLine,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home-screen', arguments: {
                      'locationWeather': args['locationWeather'], //Here I am transferring data
                      'aQI': args['aQI'],
                      'cityName': args['cityName'],
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: kYellowcolor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Get Started',
                        style: kWelcomeScreenButton,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Some part of my Home Screen

````
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();
  late int temperature;
  late Widget weatherIcon;
  late String cityName;
  late double windSpeed;
  late String description;
  late int humidity;
  late String time;
  
  List<dynamic> forecastHourlyTemp = [];
  List<int> forecastHourlyTime = [];
  List<int> forecastHourlyWeatherIcon = [];
  List<dynamic> forecastHourlyPOP = [];
  List<CardItem> items = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    updateUI(args['locationWeather'], args['aQI'], args['cityName']);  //Here I am getting error like it is saying args is undefined
    forecastHourlyTempAdd(args['locationWeather']);
    forecastHourlyTimeAdd(args['locationWeather']);
    forecastHourlyWeatherIconAdd(args['locationWeather']);
    forecastHourlyPOPAdd(args['locationWeather']);
    cardItemAdd(0);
    super.initState();
  }

  int i = 1;
  void forecastHourlyTempAdd(dynamic weatherData) {
    if (i <= 24) {
      forecastHourlyTemp.add(weatherData['hourly'][i]['temp']);
      i++;
      forecastHourlyTempAdd(args['locationWeather']);  //Here also
    }
  }

  int j = 1;
  void forecastHourlyTimeAdd(dynamic weatherData) {
    if (j <= 24) {
      forecastHourlyTime.add(weatherData['hourly'][j]['dt']);
      j++;
      forecastHourlyTimeAdd(args['locationWeather']);//Here also
    }
  }

  int k = 1;
  void forecastHourlyWeatherIconAdd(dynamic weatherData) {
    if (k <= 24) {
      forecastHourlyWeatherIcon
          .add(weatherData['hourly'][k]['weather'][0]['id']);
      k++;
      forecastHourlyWeatherIconAdd(args['locationWeather']);//Here also
    }
  }

  int l = 1;
  void forecastHourlyPOPAdd(dynamic weatherData) {
    if (l <= 24) {
      forecastHourlyPOP.add(weatherData['hourly'][l]['pop']);
      l++;
      forecastHourlyPOPAdd(args['locationWeather']);//Here also
    }
  } ```
````

Comment: You better use a state-management framework to share data between widgets. One state-management that's recommended from official docs is [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). Take a look on the [tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use post frame callback inside the initstate.

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) { 
 final map = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
})
```